# determine img dynamic request url

Tags: javascript

I currently have dynamically generated image tags on my page which reference a relative image path on my server, for example:

```
<img src="/servlet/user/{UserId}" />
```

However, when I check the request url in the network tab, what I actually see is:

```
https://MyDomaine.com/profilephoto/XXX/default
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to validate that the request url for the image referenced in my image is actually, `MyDomaine.com/profilephoto/XXX/default`, however, fetching the image's src attribute does not reflect this.

I am able to access the Dom while it is being inserted in the document by using the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) interface, however, what would be the best approach into validating that my referenced image comes from `https://MyDomaine.com/profilephoto/XXX/default` ?

The only thing i have thought of is by sending a additional request client side with each of my src urls, and see what the response has to offer contextually, but this seems a bit overkill.

Comment: Could you please explain how `/servlet/user/{UserId}` becomes `https://MyDomaine.com/profilephoto/XXX/default`?

Comment: Tue underlying cms does the conversion, I have no power over that